# Memory map large files list python

Tags: python, mmap, memory-mapped-files

Working with a list of large input files in Python, I am interested if it is possible to memory map all of them at the start of the application in order to speed up their read time. During runtime, any of the files present in the list will be read in a random manner. Is it possible to memory map them and do you think that this will help reducing their read time?

Comment: Have you tried memory mapping them and seeing if it's advantageous for your use? Not quite sure what else anyone can say here...

Answer (score 0):

If you memory map all of your large files then there is a good amount of chance that they will be paged out once your OS hits memory limits (unless you have a machine with sufficient RAM), and bringing back again in memory from Swap space will incur additional I/O effectively nulling out benefits you would have received in memory mapping them in first place.

Having said that you can use [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) function to memory map files in Python